# How to close Filter dialog in MUI datatable

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable

I am using MUI datatable in my react project. I used serverside filtering and  customFilterDialogFooter where I include **following code** in options which is passed in mui-datatables. When I click on **Apply Filters** button, I fetched data from server using my filtering criteria which is completely fine but Filter window is not closed. Is there any way to close filter window?

```
customFilterDialogFooter: filterList => {
        return (
            <div style={{marginTop: '40px'}}>
                <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => {
                    handleFilterSubmit(filterList)
                }}>Apply Filters</Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

[image: included Filter window picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter dialog is closed on the version mui-datatables": "3.0.0"

Answer (score -1):

```
<MUIDataTable
data={data}
columns={COLUMNS}
options={{ viewColumns: false }}
/>
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Also the answer is nonsense in relation to the question